# WCF serialization order issue

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, api, serialization

Recently I added a new property to a DataContract, which broke the API for our Java clients because the deserializer did not recognize the newly added property.

The solution to this apparently is to set the order attribute on the new property, so that it appears last in the SOAP message, then the deserializer will simply ignore it.

The problem is that this new property exists in the base class, and WCF always serializes the base class properties first, so the derived class properties would always appear afterwards regardless of the order attribute.

The only 2 ways I can think of to fix this are:

1. Copy the property and all of its logic to every single derived class
2. Write a custom serializer that would order things "globally"

First solution is the worst, but easiest. Second is much more difficult and risky, but the best.

Are there any other ways I can handle this situation? Is it possible to force the default WCF serializer to handle ordering differently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now I've gone with the first solution, by simply making the base property internal, and hiding it in the derived class with the "new" keyword, and now it appears at the end of the SOAP message. I haven't tested this with the clients yet, but will update here once I have.

Base class:

```
internal bool? MyNewProperty
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Derived class:

```
[DataMember(Order = 2)]
public new bool? MyNewProperty
{
    get { return base.MyNewProperty; }
    set { base.MyNewProperty= value; }
}
```

If we want to add another new property that should be backwards compatible, the Order attribute should be set to 3 (Best practice to increment with every API update).

**UPDATE:**
Even though I was able to get the element to appear last in the SOAP message, it is still a breaking change for some of our clients who are using Axis2, and it doesn't handle deserializing the new unrecognized property gracefully, even if it appears last. Related SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532353/axis2-avoid-unexpected-subelement-error-when-non-required-property-added-to-w).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the ordering sequence.
Depending on your code you could try to make the property abstract. That way you might not need to move everything to the base class.

Comment: I tried to do that and then overriding the property in all derived classes, but the derived types still appeared after the new property.

Comment: @ShahinDohan Really? Even if you set the [DataMember] tag in the derived class?

Comment: Overriding the serialiser is apparently not that hard. I guess that is the least messy option then. See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/434665/WCF-Serialization-A-Case-Study

Comment: The abstract didn't work, but hiding the base property with "new" in the derived class did the trick!

Comment: @ShahinDohan Ah Ofcourse! :) How clever of you. Maybe make it a new answer and rephrase your question a bit so future programmers who have this problem will find your solution.